# Read Excel using c# .net Issue

Tags: c#, .net, excel, windows-forms-designer

I read data from excel sheet using C#.

Here is my code and it is working.

```
var fileName = @"C:\Users\yohan\Desktop\Brandix\y.xlsx";
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=                  {0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", fileName);

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [BOM$]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable data = ds.Tables[0];
```

But it always skip the top row of the excel sheet why is that ? 
Please help ...!!

Thank You 
  yohan

Comment: If i am not mistaken, it takes the first row as Column Names. Just a hint on your connectionString: if(fileName.Trim().EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    conString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", fileName);
                }
                else if(fileName.Trim().EndsWith(".xls")) 
                {
                    conString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";", fileName);
                }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the normal behaviour of the DataAdapter. The top row is considered as an Header Row or a "Column Name" Row.

To change this behaviour add to the Extended Properties of your connection string the property "**HDR=NO**"

Example:

```
var fileName = @"C:\Users\yohan\Desktop\Brandix\y.xlsx";
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;""", fileName);

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [BOM$]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable data = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your connection string to ...

```
   "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR:No\""
```

See [this page](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel) for more possible connection strings to try.  The HDR setting determines wether the provider considers the top row to be column names.

Comment: you were faster for 20 seconds :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding HDR=NO to the extended properties.

see this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934) for details

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way to read an Excel file in Server side app is Open XML.

You can try installing ACE component but still it remains un-recommended and unsupported.

For using Open XML you can go through below links which will help you using Open XML in your code for reading excel files -

[Link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534.aspx)

[Link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478410.aspx)

[Link3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc823095.aspx)